# Search on double click

Tags: javascript, mediawiki

I am trying to trigger a search on a Mediawiki site upon double click on a word but it does not work. This is what added in Common.js.

```
document.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
    var w = String(window.getSelection());
    if (w) browser.runtime.sendMessage(null, { searchFor: w, dblClick: true });
});


function doSearch(word) {
    if (!word) return;
    word = word.replace(/[\r\n ]+/g, " ").trim();
    if (!word || word.length > 70) return;
    browser.tabs.create({
        "url": "https://lsj.gr/index.php?search=" + encodeURIComponent(word)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try `window.open()`

Working example

```
document.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
    var w = String(window.getSelection());
    if (w){
       window.open("https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?search=" + encodeURIComponent(w) )
    }
});
```

Comment: Damn, much easier than I thought! I changed `window.open` to `location.href="https://lsj.gr/index.php?search=" + encodeURIComponent(w)` to open in same page. My only problem now is how not to have it triggered when editing a wiki page and double clicking a word.

Comment: for visualEditor you could check for the `veaction` URL param, or `action` for the wikitext editor    
`var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);`
    `if (w && !urlParams.has("veaction")){`

Comment: Brilliant, Robis! Here is the full js if anybody else needs it https://lsj.gr/wiki/MediaWiki:Common.js

Comment: Is it possible not to have it triggered when a user is logged in?

Comment: Sure just check for `if (w && !mw.config.values.wgUserName)`

Comment: Wow, Robis, this is amazing, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see doSearch being called.  If you add it to your event listener, then things might work as you expect:

```
document.addEventListener("dblclick", function () {
    var w = String(window.getSelection());
    if (w){
      browser.runtime.sendMessage(null, { searchFor: w, dblClick: true });
      doSearch(w)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That did not make it work either.